# Is there a statement of Chazal about being connected even when apart?

Tags: sources-mekorot, chazal

Does anyone know a statement of Chazal that has something to do with the idea that “even though we are apart we are still connected”?

Answer (score 0):

סנהדרין כז ב

> מלמד שכולן ערבים זה בזה

Sanhedrin 27:b

It teaches us that all Jews are responsible to each other